# Can a sheet validate that a local file (referenced in cell) exists?

Tags: google-sheets

I think Google Sheets, as with most (all?) browser apps, is sandboxed so this may not be possible but...

Is there a way for Sheets to validate a local file path referenced in a cell (file exists? true/false) and/or reach out to the filesystem and change the name of said file?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, Web Applications are sandboxed in a browser so that they do not have access user's local filesystem. Therefore, Sheets cannot confirm or deny the existence of a locally stored file.